# Rails creating a user specific domain when user logs in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns, subdomain

I have created a blog `blog.com`, when a user logs in , I need to create a domain for this user, like `username.blog.com`, and he can customize this url, like `anywords.blog.com`, what can I do for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use some kind of route constraint checking for subdomain. Check Rails routing documentation for that kind of feature: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints